# FindControl in asp.net not working

Tags: asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I am using the Bootstrap collapse panel for displaying the registration form as shown below:
[image]

I want to take the PinSerialNumber from this page and display it on the next page on button click, I have done the following:

```
 Page prepage = Page.PreviousPage;
        if (prepage != null)
        {

            lblSponsorName.Text = ((TextBox)prepage.FindControl("txtSponsorName")).Text;

        }
```

But the text is not being displayed on the next page.Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you confirmed you're getting inside your if block through a breakpoint at your lblSponsorName? (as an example)

Comment: Have you declared previous page reference in the next Page?

Comment: @Deepu No I dint but without using bootstrap its working,then whats the problem here?

Comment: Can you post the markup for the previous page?

Comment: markup means? sorry dint get you

Comment: <html><head></head><body><p>Hello</p></body></html> - the 'markup'

Comment: Can you add previous page reference and try? <%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %>. Also, is it a master page?

Comment: `Pin Serial Number :<span style="color:Red;">*</span><asp:TextBox ID="txtSponsorName" 
        runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"></asp:TextBox></h4></div></td>`... this is the markup

Comment: its not the master page

Comment: OK, Are you using response.redirect to transfer request to the next page? or postback?

Comment: I have given the reference of the next page in the postback url

Comment: Where is the postback url you have defined? In button or Form?

Comment: I have added the post back url in button `<asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" 
              Text="I accept the terms and conditions.Please Register Me." onclick="Button2_Click" 
                                PostBackUrl="~/Confirmation.aspx"/>`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/58353/discussion-between-deepu-and-user2013117).

Comment: @user2013117 This seems to be taking a lot of questions for us to pry more details from you. It would be much easier to help you if you would create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Source Page code. I have added previous page reference... (NOTE:It will work with out adding previous page reference).

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <link href="http://startbootstrap.com/templates/blog-home/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link href="http://startbootstrap.com/templates/blog-home/css/blog-home.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">
          Collapsible Group Item #1
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
      <div class="panel-body">
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtSponsorName" OnTextChanged="Post" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="I accept the terms and conditions.Please Register Me." PostBackUrl="TargetPage.aspx" onclick="Post" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">
          Collapsible Group Item #2
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">
          Collapsible Group Item #3
        </a>
      </h4>
    </div>
    <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
      <div class="panel-body">
        Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div


    </div>
    </form>
        <!-- jQuery Version 1.11.0 -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap Core JavaScript -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://startbootstrap.com/templates/blog-home/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Target Page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="TargetPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.TargetPage" %>
<%@ PreviousPageType VirtualPath="~/SourcePage.aspx" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>

public partial class TargetPage : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Page prepage = Page.PreviousPage;
        if (prepage != null)
        {

            var result = ((TextBox)prepage.FindControl("txtSponsorName")).Text;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer to my question,its rather a very silly one. 
On the button click event of the previous page I had provided a PostbackURL as well as written Response.Redirect("");

Now when I removed the Response.Redirect(""); it worked fine :)

Sorry for all the trouble and thanks for taking out time to help me out.